# How can a web-component get its own styles (width etc) as soon as possible?

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element, html-imports

Consider the following `test-element` web component definition (vanilla JavaScript running on Google Chrome, not Polymer),
that creates a simple component with `width=500px`. Its `attachedCallback` function outputs its width to the console, and then sets up an asynchronous delay to do it again:

***test-element.html***

```
<style> test-element { display: inline-block; width: 500px; } </style>

<script>
    (function (window, document) {

        var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

        proto.attachedCallback = function () {

            // Direct output.
            console.log("(1) test-element.width = ", this.offsetWidth);

            // Delayed output.
            window.setTimeout(function () { console.log("(2) test-element.width = ", this.offsetWidth); }.bind(this), 0);
            };

        document.registerElement('test-element', {prototype: proto});

        })(window, document);
</script>
```

I then create a page that imports `test-element`, and outputs its width yet again from an inline script tag:

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="test-element.html">
</head>

<body>
<test-element></test-element>

<script>
    var testElement = document.querySelector('test-element');
    console.log("(3) test-element.width = ", testElement.offsetWidth);
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

The output to the console is:

```
(1) test-element.width =  0
(3) test-element.width =  500
(2) test-element.width =  500
```

This goes to prove that `attachedCallback` (1) is called before layouts and paints, which sometimes is really what I want.
For example, if I want to change its width to 100 pixels, I can make `testElement.style.width = "100px"`, and I don't need not worry about
the component flashing its previous 500px width before the callback has a chance to make the change.

However, `attachedCallback` being called before layouts sometimes is NOT what I want.
For example, if `test-element` contains a grid, and it needs to draw cells, then I need to know its width so that I can calculate how many cells
fit the available space. But I don't have this information during the `attachedCallback`, and I can't seem to grasp how to get this information.

As you can see, a 0ms delay (2) seems to trigger the layout calculation in this very simple example.
But as soon as I start doing more complicated things (for example when I have nested web components and asynchronous HTML imports), the 0ms delay is not enough, and I have to change it to a 100ms delay, and then more.

My question is: **How can I reliably get the width of the component (or any other computed styles), as soon as possible?**

Comment: You mean mutation observer? It's also before paint.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Then I would include the polyfill `webcomponents-lite.js` and listen to the `{WebComponentsReady}` event (not tested).

Comment: But my whole point here is that I want to use vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: The WebComponent.js is not part of the Polymer framework. A polyfill is

Comment: ...is vanilla-js compliant I think.

Answer (score 3):

I seem to have found the solution, using `requestAnimationFrame`:

```
proto.attachedCallback = function () {

    // This never works:
    console.log("(1) test-element.width = ", this.offsetWidth);

    // This works sometimes:
    window.setTimeout(function () { console.log("(2) test-element.width = ", this.offsetWidth); }.bind(this), 0);

    // SOLUTION - This seems to always work.
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function () { console.log("(4) test-element.width = ", this.offsetWidth); }.bind(this));
    };
```

**Note:** This is so far working OK for me, no matter how many web components I nest, and no matter how complicated I chain my HTML imports. However... does this always work? HTML parsing of HTML imports is parallelized (according to user https://stackoverflow.com/users/274673/ebidel here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports) and I don't perfectly understand the situation to be absolutely sure of this solution.

Comment: It won't work if your custom element is for example inserted inside a `flex`-styled element.

Comment: You mean because the component can be later resized? My question is about how to get the styles when the component is attached. If the component is later resized then you need to redraw it, of course, but that has nothing to do with my question. Besides, `width` and `height` are not the only styles you may be interested in. This is just an example.

Comment: Not at all. I mean the style at attached time is not the style at render time, because surrunding elements can affect the final layout.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my question: We don't have styles during the attachedCallback. And that's what `window.requestAnimationFrame` seems to address, waiting until we have the final layout. Please note (4) is not executed during attachedCallback, but at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

In your example above, the **fastest** way to get the (custom) element `width` in a `<script>` tag just after the element, exactly what you did in your test (3):

```
<test-element></test-element>

<script>
    var testElement = document.querySelector('test-element');
    console.log("(3) test-element.width = ", testElement.offsetWidth);
</script>
```

It's because HTML elements are rendered sequencially by the browser. So the script content will be executed just after the calculation of the `<test-element>` `width` and other layout properties.

```
(1) test-element.width =  0    
(3) test-element.width =  500
HTMLImportsLoaded  //with polyfill
DomContentLoaded   
window.onload
(2) test-element.width =  500
WebComponentsReady //with polyfill
```

NB: Other browser than Chrome will behave differently.

**Update**

Be careful not getting the computed style values too soon in the rendering, especially if another element is using the `requestAnimationFrame` method, too.

Below an example that shows a web component cannot always rely on this hack to know itself: the *grid* element doesn't know its rendered `width` at step (4) yet.

```js
(function(window, document) {
  var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

  proto.attachedCallback = function() {

    // Direct output.
    console.log("(1) %s.width = ", this.id, this.offsetWidth);
    this.innerHTML = "Element: " + this.id
    
    // Delayed output.
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("(2) %s.width = %s ", this.id, this.offsetWidth);
    }.bind(this), 0);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      if (this.id == "side")
        this.classList.add("large")

      console.log("(4) %s.width = %s", this.id, this.offsetWidth);
    }.bind(this));
  };

  document.registerElement('test-element', {
    prototype: proto
  });

})(window, document);
```

```css
test-element {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
}

.large {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body style="display:flex">
  <test-element id="grid"></test-element>
  <test-element id="side"></test-element>

  <script>
    var testElement = document.querySelector('test-element');
    console.log("(3) %s.width = %s", testElement.id, testElement.offsetWidth);

    window.onload = function() {
      console.log("window.onload")
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's interesting to know when the polyfill events fire, in relation to my tests. However, you are not in the web component mindset, disregarding encapsulation. My test 3 is code outside of the web component. The web component needs to render itself, so the code to get this information must be encapsulated inside its definition, not inside the page that uses the component.

Comment: In the html mindset you should not rely on the width of the element when attached or first painted to decide what to display inside. Because the element could be resized and there're no onresize events. Instead you should leverage CSS layout or rely on assertions about finally applied styles.

Comment: That's just not true. Sometimes you need style information to draw the component.

Comment: And regarding onresize events for any HTML element: http://www.backalleycoder.com/2013/03/18/cross-browser-event-based-element-resize-detection/

Comment: It's an horrible hack